# How to do "actionSheet showFromRect" in iOS 8?

Tags: uipopovercontroller, ios8, uiactionsheet, actioncontroller

In iOS 7, I show actionSheet by "showFromRect":

```
[actionSheet showFromRect:rect inView:view animated:YES];
```

But in iOS 8, this doesn't work. They they replace the implementation and suggest us using UIAlertController. Then how do I show this actionSheet like a popover?

Comment: I tried using UIPopoverController, with UIAlertController in it, still doesnt work.
    UIPopoverController *popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:alertController];

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using UIAlertController you can access the popoverPresentationController property to set the sourceView (aka inView) and sourceRect (aka fromRect). This gives the same appearance as the previous showFromRect:inView:

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

// Set the sourceView.
alert.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.mySubView;

// Set the sourceRect.
alert.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(50, 50, 10, 10);

// Create and add an Action.
UIAlertAction *anAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Action Title" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
NSLog(@"Action Pressed");
}];

[alert addAction:anAction];

// Show the Alert.
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 3):

I also meet this problem like you, but my case is that I show a `UIActionSheet` in `UIWindow.view` on the iPad device, and the `UIWindow` doesn't set `rootViewController`.

So, I found, if we show a `UIActionSheet` in a window whose `rootViewController` equals to `nil`, the `UIActionSheet` could not show out.

My solution is to set

```
window.rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
```

then,

```
[actionSheet showFromRect:rect inView:window.rootViewController.view animated:YES].
```

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score -1):

I found out the point is in iOS 7, you show `actionSheet` in a new window actually when using `"showFromRect: inView:"` ;

But in iOS 8 you show the `actionSheet` just on the view you send in parameters.

So the solution is to send

```
self.superView
    [actionSheet showFromRect:rect inView:[self.superView] animated:YES];
```

Me and my colleague figured it out by randomly trying.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work in popovers: `Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged <UIViewController: 0x7a67fba0>. `

Answer (score -1):

according to this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/index.html thread 
UIActionSheet is deprecated, you should use UIAlertController instead of UIActionSheet.

Thanks.